# What file system do I have installed?

Tags: command-line, filesystem

Is there any way to check it from command line?

Comment: I just had to point out that there is some subtleties with this question. Does "installed" include filesystems that are supported by the kernel but you don't have any drives formatted with that; also how do you define "installed" when talking about FUSE. How about non-local "filesystems"? Also, do you consider devfs, debugfs, procfs, ramdisk as "filesystems"?

Comment: @Lie Ryan I meant what filesystem the system partition is using

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can also check it by `df -T`

Sample output:

```
Filesystem    Type   1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/hdb1     ext3    19228276  14737848   3513680  81% / 
tmpfs        tmpfs      383960         4    383956   1% /dev/shm
```

You can also try `df -hT`

From `man df`:

```
-h, --human-readable
              print sizes in human readable format (e.g., 1K 234M 2G)
-T, --print-type
              print file system type
```

Answer (score 19):

Just type `mount`, it will show all mounted devices and what fs type they are mounted as.

Answer (score 9):

You could also do a `sudo fdisk -l`

```
nits@nits-excalibur:~$ sudo fdisk -l
[sudo] password for nits: 
Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x27edc0d3

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      206847      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          206848   188743679    94268416    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       224569342   976771071   376100865    5  Extended
/dev/sda4       188743680   224567295    17911808   83  Linux
/dev/sda5       224569344   434284543   104857600    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda6       434286592   644001791   104857600    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda7       644003840   684001279    19998720   83  Linux
/dev/sda8       684003328   704002047     9999360   83  Linux
/dev/sda9       804003840   972767231    84381696   83  Linux
/dev/sda10      704004096   744001535    19998720   83  Linux
/dev/sda11      744003584   803987455    29991936   83  Linux
/dev/sda12      972769280   976771071     2000896   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Partition table entries are not in disk order
```

`sudo blkid` gives you information about the format of the partition along with its UUID and label if any.

```
nits@nits-excalibur:~$ sudo blkid
[sudo] password for nits: 
/dev/sda1: LABEL="System Reserved" UUID="22F2DE0DF2DDE4D7" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda2: UUID="6E5E0E255E0DE6A5" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda4: LABEL="TestDrive" UUID="e6e47b0b-4c88-43f9-9165-81b2c1af4d1c" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda5: LABEL="Storage_1" UUID="42DC637EDC636B5D" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda6: LABEL="Storage_2" UUID="D890877C9087603C" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda7: UUID="b73e274d-fdb2-45ac-acfe-9fcb48631ff7" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda8: UUID="831304eb-1ee5-486c-a4a4-ef40b6c2d4dc" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda9: UUID="9ba518d1-4a03-4b92-9b31-15db045c8cd4" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda10: UUID="dcc15cd3-041d-4ad2-915e-9c0dae9310c7" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda11: UUID="3ad60b50-a4f3-4dff-b62e-610766e1b119" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda12: UUID="5604929a-9d9e-4ab0-907f-b9479a3b55e5" TYPE="swap"
```

The two commands in conjunction with each other should be enough to get the information about partitions on your system.

Comment: This doesn't show what filesystems you have on the partitions. Not sure about windows* but in linux you could have any of these partitions formatted in any way.

Comment: @forcefsck: Thanks for pointing it out :) I have now added `blkid` information to my answer.

Comment: +1 Now it's more complete, since it shows info for all partitions and not only for the mounted ones.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know what filesystem types are supported by your kernel,

```
cat /proc/filesystems
```

Comment: The OP clearly stated that he did not mean that in the comment section under the question. -1.

Comment: You're right, I didn't notice it. Sorry.